# sum dictionary values based on matched key words found via nested loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, sum, bioinformatics

Trying to add up all the values in dict with keys that contain elements in lstA and group according to lstA. But the following code renders the sum of all the dict values. How do I resolve this?

To illustrate:

```
lstA = ['R0', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3']
lstB = [('R0', 'R1'), ('R0', 'R2'), ('R0', 'R3'), ('R0', 'R4'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3'), ('R2', 'R3')]
dict = {('R0', 'R1'): 0.04, ('R0', 'R2'): 0.05, ('R0', 'R3'): 0.03, ('R1', 'R2'): 0.1, ('R1', 'R3'): 0.06, ('R2', 'R3'): 0.074}

output = []
for i in range(len(lstA)):
    for j in range(len(lstB)):
        if lstA[i] in lstB[j]:
            result += dict[lstB[j]]
output.append(result)
print(output)
```

Comment: What is the expected output of the above?

Comment: Agree with Vasilis; you should probably provide a short sample `lstA`, `lstB` and `dict` and use them to explain what you want the code to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a problem of indentation, what you're trying to do is:

```
lstA = ['R0', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3']
lstB = [('R0', 'R1'), ('R0', 'R2'), ('R0', 'R3'), ('R0', 'R4'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3'), ('R2', 'R3')]
dic = {('R0', 'R1'): 0.04, ('R0', 'R2'): 0.05, ('R0', 'R3'): 0.03, ('R1', 'R2'): 0.1, ('R1', 'R3'): 0.06, ('R2', 'R3'): 0.074}

output = []
for i in range(len(lstA)):
    result = 0
    for j in range(len(lstB)):
        if lstA[i] in lstB[j] and lstB[j] in dic:
            result += dic[lstB[j]]
    output.append(result)
print(output)
```

Comment: Just ran this. It throws `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`. Consider modifying it.

Comment: It's because the dictionary shouldn't be called `dict`

Comment: Correct. Thanks!

Comment: I've modified my answer with a correct name for the dictionary.

Comment: Modified my answer to check that the keys are in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

- Elements of key are in LstA
- key is also in LstB

  ```
  result = 0
  output = []
  for key, value in dict.items():
      element1, element2 = key
      if (element1 in lstA and element2 in lstA
          and key in lstB):
          result += value
          output.append(value)
  print(result, output)
  0.35400000000000004 [0.04, 0.05, 0.03, 0.1, 0.06, 0.074]
  ```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic version of @LouisSugy's answer

```
>>> lst_a = ['R0', 'R1', 'R2', 'R3']
... lst_b = [('R0', 'R1'), ('R0', 'R2'), ('R0', 'R3'), ('R0', 'R4'), ('R1', 'R2'), ('R1', 'R3'), ('R2', 'R3')]
... d = {('R0', 'R1'): 0.04, ('R0', 'R2'): 0.05, ('R0', 'R3'): 0.03, ('R1', 'R2'): 0.1, ('R1', 'R3'): 0.06, ('R2', 'R3'): 0.074}
... 
>>> output = []
... for elem in lst_a:
...     result = 0
...     for pair in lst_b:
...         if elem in pair:
...             try:
...                 result += d[pair]
...             except KeyError:
...                 pass
...     output.append(result)
... 
>>> output
[0.12, 0.2, 0.22400000000000003, 0.16399999999999998]
```

I'm not sure what the point of `lst_b` is though. If you are skipping them if they don't have a matching key in `d` then why not just iterate through the keys of `d`? This gives the same result with no potential `KeyError`s (the `and lstB[j] in dic` part in the accepted answer).

```
>>> output = []
... for elem in lst_a:
...     result = 0
...     for key_pair, value in d.items():
...         if elem in key_pair:
...             result += value
...     output.append(result)
... 
>>> output
[0.12, 0.2, 0.22400000000000003, 0.16399999999999998]
```